# SQL stored procedure local variable error #1064

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, local-variables

I am working for a little film database with php and mysql. And i got a problem when I want to create a stored procedure, that the local variable don't work in the case i want to use it.

```
    delimiter //
### showFilm###
create procedure showFilm( in id INTEGER )
BEGIN
    DECLARE tmp_Value varchar(50);

    IF ( id = 0) THEN SET tmp_Value = "";
    ELSE SET tmp_Value = concat('where = ', id);    

    END IF;

    select f.Titel, f.Jahr, f.Bewertung, f.altersfreigabe, f.Beschreibung, f.Trailer, f.Dateipfad, f.Titelbild, f.Speichermedium, r.Vorname, r.Nachname, r.Land, r.Bild 
        from film as f
        inner join regisseur as r 
        on r.idRegisseur = f.idFilm tmp_Value;
END;
//
```

Comment: mysql <> sql-server ?

Comment: okay sry that was my fault I am using MySQL

Comment: You can use a [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) or you can use a `WHERE` statement like the following: `... WHERE [your_column] = [sp_parameter] OR [sp_parameter] = 0`, (`[your_column]` must be greater than zero (0)). You can evaluate possible performance problems.